# math operations in relational alegebra

Tags: relational-database, relational-algebra

A very simple question about relational algebra that I cannot find any answer in internet or/and some books.

Suppose the relation employee(key,salary,bonus), and I want to create a new relation R(key,totalMoney) where totalMoney = salary + bonus. My try is:

R1(key,totalMoney) = projection *key,salary* (employee)

R2(key,totalMoney) = projection *key,bonus* (employee)

R = *key* aggregate sum *totalMoney* (R1 U R2)

Is it ok?

If it is ok, however, it is not resolve all my problems :(

Suppose I now want to get RT2(key, totalMoney * 2). For this, my attempt is:

RT2 = update *totalMoney* <- totalMoney*2 (R)   //"update" is a relational algebra operator

Is it ok?

I think my answers are not (very) good. If you can help me to find a nice and neat solution, I will appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: This appears to be off-topic and not related [directly] to programming. Unfortunately it would also not fit the "level" of the math stackexchange :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codd's original algebra did not include such an operation because he firmly believed that such computations should be done in the application.

And alas most of what is being taught these days is still very close to these original ideas of Codd's.  Which are 40 years old by now.  And so all the evolutions that have taken place during those 40 years are, alas, mostly overlooked.

One of those things is the EXTEND operator that was introduced, somewhere along the line, by Chris Date & Hugh Darwen I believe.  This operator takes care of exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Traditional relational algebra [does not support](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397502007363) arithmetic operations. However, different attempts have been made to extend it: for instance [Gabbay and McBrian](http://compscinet.dcs.kcl.ac.uk/staff/dg/083.pdf) discuss arithmetic extensions of selection and projection operators, while [Boncz et al.](http://doc.utwente.nl/63538/1/p1322-boncz.pdf) have proposed a number of relational algebra extensions (including arithmetic operations) for their XQuery compiler Pathfinder.

Comment: I think Gabbay and McBrian does not try supporting math operators in relational algebra. The authors extend to temporal queries (using since and until operators). 

So, my proposed solutions to do get math operations are appropriated? I expect the answer is no!

Comment: Indeed, the focus of Gabbay and McBrian is on temporal queries but to translate these to relational algebra they need some form of arithmetic.